# Efficient ways to spend gold when returning from afk?

Tags: league-of-legends

While playing a 5v5, our Maoki's client crashed for the first 11 minutes.  Upon return he purchased a [Giant's Belt](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Giant%27s_Belt), lvl 1 boots, and a few other trivial items.  The extra HP kept him alive when the enemy team immediately targeted him.

This got me wondering, what items most effectively help a character gain experience/gold when returning from a disconnect?

Reference: 
[Gold](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gold) is passively generated at at 13 gold/10 seconds (78/min) in addition to the starting 475.

Comment: I'd think that this would be pretty subjective depending on which champ you're talking about. For example, a very gold efficient AD item won't be that helpful on an AP caster, in general.

Comment: It certainly depends on champion/role, but I think a generic "this item is good for this role" answer is possible (and encouraged!).

Comment: Good question by the way. I posted an answer, i hope may help you, and i hope is clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, how you spend your money when returning from AFK is determined by your role on the team. I will just give a list of various champion types and suggestions.

1. **Tanky/Tanky-DPS** - I would almost always recommend grabbing something like heart of gold for those health dependant champions or maybe a philosophers stone for those mana dependent champions (Moakai, Amumu, Leona). These items will help you gain some of that lost gold back while still offering you a great advantage for the price. Plus both of these items are in the recipe for a few awesome items. If you have enough get your boots so you can escape the inevitable ganks.
2. **Ranged AD** - For a ranged AD/carry I would say pick up **at least** tier 1 boots if not finish them off. You are going to need to stay mobile in the event your lane has been pushed back a tower. Also everyone is going to be out to get you because you are probably underleveled. Luckily you shine late game, so if you can grab some lifesteal, maybe a Doran's Blade or two dependant on how long you've been AFK and get to farming. The Doran's items offer great benefits at low cost.
3. **AP/Casters** - For AP casters I would probably also reccomened a philosophers stone (you can sell it later) and at least tier one boots. AP Casters are very item dependant, and that AP scaling can benefit you greatly. I would grab the highest +AP item you can afford with your tier one boots that ties into one of your build items and hit the lane. You will need that AP boost to take out the minions efficiently because they scale with the game length.
4. **Fighters** - For a fighting active champion I would recommend boots and just flat health. They taking a beating and usually don't build a lot of armor. If you are planning on playing tankier then go with some armor. Maybe the cloth or if you're lucky the chain. Make sure to grab a health/armor item that converts into a higher tier item you utilize.
5. **General** - Generally speaking, the gold per second items are great choices because they offer great benefits stats and gold wise. Also the Doran's items are great choices because they too pack a punch. Stack a few Doran's Blade and noone will ever know you left. You also want to keep in mind though your farming capabilities. Do something that will keep you alive and out of harms way in that lane to bounce back gold and XP wise.

Comment: heart of gold and philosophers stone are not so great because take 27.5 minutes to you recovery the gold spend on each. they are great items for early game, but in end game you usually finish build them into something else or even sell them.

Comment: Not always true, some gold > no gold. Plus awesome stats for their price. Also heart of gold and philosophers stone both convert into 2 very popular items for those classes (Radiuns Omen and Shuyleys (spelling...) Reverie)

Comment: I think this is great advice for short-term disconnects.  I wouldn't buy gp/10 items unless I'm very sure they'll have time to pay for themselves though!

Comment: Agreed, this answer was based on an 11 minute disconnect time, which leaves you plenty of time to recover. Some people who buy philostone or heart of gold might not even get it while playing until like 8 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The best options Would always be:

- Health pool (to keep you alive)
- Moviment (to make the recal easy and keep you alive)
- Damage (to help you farm minions and get back your level)

The best options (*In my opinion and experience*), to each one of the options above, depends on **What is your champion** and **Who is your opponent**

For instance:

- Vayne would do great with a [Bloodthirster](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Bloodthirster) and Boots,
- But with a Rammus, i would go for [Glacial Shroud](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Glacial_Shroud) and Boots

I am saying what I already saw in the game. People who **ALWAYS** follow the same order usually are not happy when DC occurs.

Comment: You would have to DC for 32 minutes to afford a bloodthirster though!

Comment: I Saw a Vayne DC for 48min she came back with this set of items, and stay clearing minions from top and mid while we where fighting at dragon and bot, she get our level and gear with 8min and we won in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think the item you buy when reconnecting to a game is as important as safely catching up on levels. The problem is, no matter what you buy if you are 6+ levels lower then the enemy team, you will get killed by any confrontation.

I had a friend in this situation and we used the **buddy system**, never letting him go anywhere alone until he finally caught up on levels and got enough farm to actually have a chance in team fights.

So, the items you would want to purchase would be ones to help you accomplish this goal. Items such as level 2 boots to move with your teammate are appropriate, as well as Doran's items due to their very high gold/stat value.

Comment: Good advice, but the question is specifically about items.  Could you edit your answer to include what item you think is most important, or general item buying advice?